# About the sum $ s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \text{lcm}(k,n) $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I'm currently studying the following sum:
$$
s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \text{lcm}(k,n)
$$
I manipulated it as follows:
$$\begin{align}
s_n&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \text{lcm}(k,n)\\
&=\sum_{d|n}{\sum_{(k,n)=d,\space 1≤k≤n}\frac{kn}{d}}\\
&=n\sum_{d|n}{\sum_{\left(k,\frac{n}{d}\right)=1,\space 1≤k≤\frac{n}{d}}k}\\
&=n\sum_{d|n}\frac{n}{2d}\varphi\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\\
&=\frac{n}{2}\sum_{d|n}d\varphi(d)
\end{align}
$$
I don't now if the can be broken down further. Is it possible to obtain a closed form expression? Or at least an asymptote? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It may or may not help you to note that $\sum_{d \mid n} d \phi(d)$ is a multiplicative function in $n$. (I don't know whether it does help, but I don't have time to follow that up now.)

Comment: Also, $d\phi(d)=\phi(d^2)$.

Comment: As Patrick said, it's a multiplicative function, we have: $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{d \vert n} d\varphi (d) = \prod_{p^\alpha \Vert n} \frac{p^{2\alpha+1}+1}{p+1}$

Comment: See [OEIS A$51193$](http://oeis.org/A051193).